# Prestashop Public Stock list

Tags: controller, smarty, prestashop

I'm running Prestashop 1.6.1.7 and I'm looking for a quick way to display a product list with all various attributes and their stock levels on a page. The page would be public however it wouldn't be listed or linked to from anywhere on the main site so we can send the link to retailers and suppliers and they will have an accurate record of our current stock in real time without giving them access to our admin area.

I assume I need to modify a controller in order to get the correct variables onto the page but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**tl;dr  - How do I modify a custom page controller to get an array with product names, attributes and stock levels onto it.**

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, you should create a custom module with a custom front controller. This custom front controller can be used to display the list of products and can be accessed from anywhere without gaining access to the admin panel.

Take a look at the following link to get the details on how to implement a custom front controller:

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/342774-add-custom-php-page-prestashop-16/

In order to fetch all the products from PrestaShop, following function can be used:

```
Product::getProducts();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! So I've got a custom page set up with it's own custom controller which extends from the front controller. How do I declare Product::getProducts(); as an array? I gave it a quick go with no luck, I tried adding the following to initcontent:       $stocklist = Product::getProducts();
       $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'stocklist' => $stocklist));
    }

Comment: [17-Feb-2017 11:05:58 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 5 for ProductCore::getProducts(), called in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/controllers/front/stocklistController.php on line 22 and defined in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/classes/Product.php on line 1190